# Redrawing custom marker in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have created a custom marker and added it in draw control toolbar like this :

```
L.Draw.myMarker = L.Draw.Marker.extend({
    initialize : function(map, options) {
        this.type = 'myMarker';
        L.Draw.Feature.prototype.initialize.call(this, map, options);
    }
});
```

Now I can draw this marker on my map from my draw control toolbar.

**Requirements :**

Further I need to save the details of all myMarker in database (latlong ,options etc). Later I need to redraw the same markers by fetching the details from DB and then displaying them on map.

**Problem :**  
I only found one solution to re-create marker that is:

```
//Step 1. Extending marker with Marker class
L.myMarker = L.Marker.extend({});
//Step 2. Recreating marker with the persisted data
L.myMarker([lat, long], {}).addTo(map);
```

But I want to create instance of `L.Draw.myMarker` that I drawn previously by toolbar.

So I need something like this `L.Draw.myMarker([lat, long], {}).addTo(map);`

Comment: Do you really need custom marker functionality, or just a custom icon for markers?

Comment: I am creating custom markers with different types. So I need all functionality to create popup on markers and everything.  I can create markers and save their postions and details lat lng in db but I can't redraw them on map load (from db) because of the above given problem.

Comment: Different types meaning what? I'm asking because I think you are creating extra complexity where you only need custom `L.icon` functionality supported by both Leaflet.Draw and Leaflet by itself..

Comment: I created two type of markers , so that I can get two markers in draw control bar of leaflet. Now I can click on the draw toolbar and draw my custom created markers (with custom icon).  Once drawn ,I saved their details in DB. Now I want to recreate them on map load. For this I need to do something like this  : <br>  L.Draw.myMarker([lat, long], {}).addTo(map);     . So my question in simple term is :   I draw a marker using draw toolbar and saved their latlongs in db. Now how to redraw them on map load (Without mannual draw)? How to create a marker behind the scene and place it on map?

Answer (score 1):

Given your circumstances, I think you are going to have to duplicate some of your custom marker logic in something that extends from `L.Marker` to be able to use it outside of the Leaflet.draw context...because `L.Draw.Marker` extends from `L.Draw.Feature`(https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/master/src/draw/handler/Draw.Marker.js#L1), while Leafet's Marker extends from `L.Layer`(https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/marker/Marker.js#L5)..So that's not exactly a clear inheritance tree to be overriding things with between those two.

Comment: So is there any alternative available ?? Or the only alternative is that I provided above in solution section ? Kindly suggest. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't really see an alternative. If Leaflet.Draw had options for multiple buttons for the same base 'type'(but different class) of feature, then things might be different.